# document.getElementById().innerHTML wont update with a 2d array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to update multiple `<div>` without refreshing the whole page and figured that if I cycle through an array using the `index` I can achieve that, but it's not working at all.

However when I replace  `event[index]['fullName']` in the `prevEvent` function with `index`, the page gets updated.

How do I update the page contents without refreshing the whole page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 var index=0;
//pass php array to javascript
  var event= <?php echo json_encode($event); ?>;
  document.getElementById("fullName").innerHTML = event[index]['fullName'];
  document.getElementById("emailAddress").innerHTML = event[index]['emailAddress'];
  document.getElementById("phoneNumber").innerHTML = event[index]['phoneNumber'];
  document.getElementById("childName").innerHTML = event[index]['childName'];
  document.getElementById("theater").innerHTML = event[index]['theater'];
  document.getElementById("movie").innerHTML = event[index]['movie'];
  document.getElementById("eventDate").innerHTML = event[index]['eventDate'];
  document.getElementById("eventTime").innerHTML = event[index]['eventTime'];
  document.getElementById("eventType").innerHTML = event[index]['eventType'];
  document.getElementById("numOfPeople").innerHTML = event[index]['numOfPeople'];
  document.getElementById("partyRoomBook").innerHTML = event[index]['partyRoomBook'];
  document.getElementById("partyRoomTime").innerHTML = event[index]['partyRoomTime'];
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = event[index]['description'];
  document.getElementById("specialAttention").innerHTML = event[index]['specialAttention'];



  function prevEvent(){
    index--;
    document.getElementById("fullName").innerHTML = event[index]['fullName'];

  }

</script>
```

Comment: AJAX is what you need to use.

Comment: *"its not working at all"* - Any errors shown in the console? What calls `prevEvent()`? Are you saying `event` holds all of the required data but you only want to show the fields from one index at a time?

Comment: Why are you subtracting from `index` in `prevEvent()`, then trying to use it as an index in your `.innerHTML` assignments? `index` starts at `0`, so you'll be attempting to access negative indexes.